# Cannot access PHP Object as Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am facing a strange problem. It may just be a silly mistake, and I am just missing some basics.

I'm running php 5.6.1 on MAMP.

I have a simple array which I get from a mysql query. Using a `foreach` loop, I can `print_r()` each value, which gives me: `stdClass Object ( [srno] => 6 [link] => this-is-link )`

Now I can `echo $obj->srno`, and that prints fine. But I can't use `echo $obj['srno']` which I was previously using, on an older version of PHP, but- It shows nothing.

Any help really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: PHP classes are not normally accessible as arrays, only those which implement `ArrayAccess`

Comment: You are getting an array of `stdClass`objects and you can't access stdClass object's property like `array`. If your query returns an array of arrays then you are able to access that as an array, so the question is what are you using for your `DB` query? Probably you can change the return type to `Array` instead of `stdClass`.

Comment: `->` in PHP is not a pointer !!!

Comment: @LorenzMeyer yeah, but couldn't find exact word. 
@TheAlpha I am using codeIgniter `result()` to return rows.
I am sure I was able to use the same code before. Something changed in php 5.6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `stdClass` object and need to address it as an array, you can cast it to array quite easily:

```
$someObj = new stdClass();
$someObj->foo = "bar";

$someArray = (array)$someObj; // Cast the object to an array

echo $someArray['foo']; // Will give you "bar"
```

Working example: http://3v4l.org/nni1Y

Of course as comments already pointed out, you may want to look at retrieving your mysql results as an array in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

As you said your results return as an object so you can use it by using 
$obj->your_field_name to display field value. But your can not use by $obj['field_name'];